# What does add [rax],al mean in x86_64 assembly and what mnemonic description does it fit in?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I was doing some reversing with cheat engine and i came across these add [rax],al instructions which seemingly do nothing (i may be incorrect), it seems that after every ret instruction these add [rax],al instructions appear as seen in the screenshot:[image: Memory]

I also wonder what type of mnemonic this instruction fits in such as the ones you can see on this screenshot:[image: Mnemonics]

I have tried putting a few breakpoints on these add [rax],al instructions but the breakpoints seem to not get hit, and my initial guess for the mnemonic was it being a "add m64,r8" but the opcode on the screenshot for add [rax],al is "00 00" which doesnt fit in the mnemonic i described, also there are no such mnemonics on the Mnemonics screenshot similar to "add m64,r8", the reason i think the first operand is a m64 is because its [rax] which is a 64 bit register enclosed by square brackets, i hope someone can shed light on this subject.

Comment: It's `00 /r ADD r/m8, r8`. Note the 8 means the operand size, not the address size. It's adding a 8 bit register to a 8 bit register or memory (which is nevertheless addressed by 64 bits). The only reason it does nothing is because it's after the `ret`. The disassembler is just decoding the zero bytes that were inserted as padding for alignment.

Comment: More than 99% of the time, if you see `add [rax],al` you're not looking at something that is meant to be executed. It's a valid instruction, but almost never would you actually add the lowest byte of the address of a byte to that byte itself. That's an odd thing to do.